# To display top 4 rows using mysql Rank is displaying wrong

Tags: mysql

I need to display the top4 and lease 4 rows based Amount and group by agentId but here rank is showing wrong
And how to show least(last 4 rows?)
  schema:

```
 AgentID amount 
    1      3000
    1      3200
    2      9000
 SELECT Agentid,SUM(AmountRecevied) as Amount,@rownum := @rownum + 1 AS Rank
 FROM collection ,(SELECT @rownum := 0) r
 GROUP BY AgentID
 ORDER BY Amount DESC
 limit 4;
```

[image]

Comment: how did you say "rank is showing wrong"?

Comment: here based on amount if 800000 is the higher amount it's should display the rank 1 but it's showing 4

Comment: My question is why do you need to calculate rank in query? Top most is 1, second is 2 and so on..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
SELECT T.Agentid,T.Amount, @rownum := @rownum - 1 AS Rank
 FROM
 (SELECT Agentid,SUM(AmountRecevied) as Amount
 FROM collection 
 GROUP BY AgentID
 ORDER BY Amount
 LIMIT 4) T,(SELECT @rownum := 11) r
```

Comment: How to display last four rows? here it's working fine

Comment: Last four rows means?

Comment: last least four  amount like last four ranks if 10  ranks than should show 7,8,9,10

Comment: @sandeep: edited my answer. Try it now. I think that is what you are after. If not, please let me know.

Comment: @sandeep: Your understanding and explanation on assiging rank seems unclear. From your posted query, most of those on SO assume that highest amount record will have highest rank, i.e. 1.

Comment: @RagingBull: Your edited answer may give wrong results, if that many number of records does not exist.

Comment: rank are displaying like 9,8,7,6

Comment: i added this order by Rank asc fine now

Comment: hi Raging Bull small doubt i don't want to display the rank for last four rows how to do that?

Comment: @sandeep: You mean, you don't want to show rank, but it should select other columns?

Comment: @sandeep: Can you show me the query you are trying. I will give it a try.

Comment: same query which you give to me i am tiring with that

Comment: @sandeep: last 4 rows means 10,9,8,7?

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS Rank  FROM  (SELECT Agentid,SUM(AmountRecevied) as Amount  FROM collection   ' at line 1

Comment: @sandeep. I think we can't select some all fields from one column and some fields from another column unless we use subquery and joins...which will be a bad idea (considering the performance).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54762/discussion-between-sandeep-and-raging-bull).

Comment: When multiple agents have same amount then ranks differ with this solution. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT
   C.*,
   @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS Rank
FROM (
   SELECT
     Agentid,
     SUM(AmountRecevied) as Amount
   FROM collection
   GROUP BY AgentID
   ORDER BY Amount DESC
   LIMIT 4
) AS C, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of `amount` matching for different `agentid`s, then, I believe, ranks should be assigned same.

This solution should help you:

```
select 
  /*case when rank>6 then '' else rank end as */
  rank, agentid, amount
from (
  select agentid, @ca:=amount amount
    , case when @pa=@ca then @rn:=@rn
           else @rn:=( @rn + 1 )
      end as rank
      , @pa:=@ca as temp_currAmount
  from ( select agentid, sum(amount) as amount 
         from agents
         group by agentid 
         order by amount
        ) amounts_summary,
       (select @pa:=0, @c0:=0, 
               @rn:=0) row_nums
  order by rank desc 
) results 
where rank > 6
order by rank
;
```

**Demo** @ [*MySQL 5.6.6 Fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0541c/1)

And if you want no display ranks greater than `'6'` but empty, then
just uncomment the `case` line and comment the `where` condition line

```
select 
  case when rank>6 then '' else rank end as 
  rank, agentid, amount
from (
  select agentid, @ca:=amount amount
    , case when @pa=@ca then @rn:=@rn
           else @rn:=( @rn + 1 )
      end as rank
      , @pa:=@ca as temp_currAmount
  from ( select agentid, sum(amount) as amount 
         from agents
         group by agentid 
         order by amount
        ) amounts_summary,
       (select @pa:=0, @ca:=0, 
               @rn:=0) row_nums
  order by rank
) results 
-- where rank > 6
order by rank
;
```

You can modify `asc` or `desc` as required.

**Demo** @ [*MySQL 5.6.6 Fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0541c/2)